# Application not appearing after launching from visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a strange problem, which i have never seen before , i have a wpf application and i am using prism for mvvm and sqlserverCe 4 for database, today i uninstalled sqlserverCe and prism packages from the executable project and re installed them back, now when i launch the application from visual studio 2012/13 the application is not appearing on the screen. the build output window shows the following.

---

> Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.Main'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.InitializeComponent'
>   'NewPos.Main.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NewPos.Main.vshost.exe): Loaded 'F:\Practise\NewPos\NewPos.Main\bin\Debug\NewPos.MenuModule.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   The thread 0x138c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>   The thread 0x2d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x118c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Double clicking the application icon directly also does nothing. I am scratching my head and wondering what has gone wrong with it

**Things that i did before the application seized to appear**

- uninstall and re install prism package because service locator package was referencing .net45 and i changed the target framework to .net4 on the project.
- uninstall and re install  the sqlserverCE package becasuse of the same above reason.

Comment: Check what it says in the `packages.config` and `*.csproj` files WRT the packages you use, and compare to what is actually present in the `packages` folder.

Comment: Post your xaml code please.

Comment: @Sonhja you solved it for me. when i checked app.xamal for copying here its encoding was changed.i change that back to the original and the application is now appearing.But i am wondering how did the   encoding of app.xaml changed.Anyways my problem is solved